# RShiny : checkBox format

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

Current status of the boxes : 
[image]

I am unable to improve the following things :

1. Have the text in a row by itself(The Select the modules... one)
2. The box and text are not aligned on the same line.
3. The checkboxes on the top line are slightly truncated.(the remaining is encircled below)
4. The labels(a to j) need to be in white bold text.

This is what I have tried so far :

## ui.R :

```
library(shiny)
controls <- list(tags$div(align = 'left', 
                class = 'multicol', 
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId  = 'modules', 
                                   label    = "Step 1 : Select the modules to be executed", 
                                   choices  = c(process_names),
                                   selected = "",
                                   inline   = FALSE)))
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$style(type='text/css', "label {font-size: 22px; }            # controls the text of check-boxes
             .form-group {margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
             .nav-tabs {font-family:'arial';font-size:20px}
             #sidebar {background-color: #5C97BF;}
             #mainbar {background-color: #5C97BF;}
             body { background-color: #002B55;}
             input[type=checkbox] {transform: scale(2);}
             .multicol {height: 200px; -webkit-column-count: 4; 
             -moz-column-count: 4;    /* Firefox */
             column-count: 4; -moz-column-fill: auto;-column-fill: auto;} # increases the size of checkboxes
             div.checkbox {margin-top: 10px;color:'#FFFFFF';font-weight: bold; }
             .btn {display:block;height: 60px;width: 40px;border-radius: 50%;} # for actionButton
             "),

  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel(controls),
    mainPanel()
  )
))
```

## server.R

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output){

  }
)
```

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem so far. Is `process_names <- letters[1:13]`? And where do you get the `my_div`function from? Will be much easier if you provide a full reproducible app!

Comment: @BigDataScientist you can just ignore the `my_div()` function. Just a customised version. Actually I ran this n my colleague'ssystem and things are working well for him. I guess its system specific.

Comment: just a friendly FYI. Given the code above i cant reproduce the picture at the top. Should be easy to post a fully reproduc. app,... Maybe you are in luck and others can reproduce. Have a good week!

Comment: @BigDataScientist I agree, I have updated the code. You should be able to reproduce it now. I want to avoid the truncation that is happening

Comment: @joel.wilson the code is still not reproducable. You need to define `process_names`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's fixed code for your app:

```
library(shiny)
process_names <- letters[1:13]
controls <- tags$div(
  tags$label("Step 1 : Select the modules to be executed"),
  tags$div(align = 'left', 
           class = 'multicol', 
           checkboxGroupInput(inputId  = 'modules', 
                              label    = NULL, 
                              choices  = c(process_names),
                              selected = "",
                              inline   = FALSE)))
ui<-(fluidPage(
  tags$style(type='text/css', "label {font-size: 22px; }           
             .form-group {margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
             .nav-tabs {font-family:'arial';font-size:20px}
             #sidebar {background-color: #5C97BF;}
             #mainbar {background-color: #5C97BF;}
             body { background-color: #002B55;}
             input[type=checkbox] {transform: scale(2);margin-top:10px;}
             .multicol {height: 200px; -webkit-column-count: 4; 
             -moz-column-count: 4;    /* Firefox */
             column-count: 4; -moz-column-fill: auto;-column-fill: auto;} 
             .checkbox {margin-top:-5px;}
             .btn {display:block;height: 60px;width: 40px;border-radius: 50%;} 
             #modules .checkbox label span {font-weight:bold;}
             label {color:#fff;}
             "),

  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel(controls),
    mainPanel()
  )
  ))

server<-function(input,output){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This takes care of all your issues. Note that one big problem you had (that took me a long time to debug!) is that you cannot use `#` as comments inside CSS. That breaks your CSS. You can only use `/* comment here */` as comments in CSS.

Comment: brilliant !! This worked! Thank you for the "comment" tip too! Is there a simple link for "R" guys to learn basics of CSS/HTML ?

Comment: Not really. CSS is a fairly general skill that's useful in a ton of web stuff, and it's 100% transferrable. Going through some basic css tutorials should be good enough

Answer (score 2):

1. To have the label on a single line, set `label = NULL` and add a `p("text")` before the `checkBox()` to have it on a single line.
2. To have the text in 'white', add a `style="color:#FFFFFF"` to the `list(tags$div()`.
3. I'm still trying to figure out why the boxes are slightly truncated.